# Recommended simulator for drone project

Tags: ros2, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ROS and I would appreciate some help. I am currently working on a drone that does not need someone to pilot it and that is able to pick up objects. I would also would appreciate advice in the ROS version that I should pick. I thought about choosing ROS 2 Galactic but I don't know if that affects the simulator that I can choose. I am looking for a simulator that:

1. has sensors (a camera) to see object to pick up
2. has a gripper to collect
3. can potentially be purchased (the drone exists in reality)

I have been looking into V-Rep (Coppelia Slim), Gazebo, and Webots but I can’t seem to find if all the above conditions are fulfilled by any of them. Webots for example seems a very good option but I could not seem to find the option of the gripper. V-Rep seems good as well but it does not have very nice tutorials.
I appreciate any advice that the community can give me.

Thank you in advance.

AaronVG

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/393295/recommended-simulator-for-drone-project/) by [AaronVG](https://answers.ros.org/users/92046/aaronvg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-12-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Webots has everything you need:

- It is very easy to add cameras and all sorts of sensors to Webots, there are plenty of examples in the webots_ros2 package.
- Here is an example of a Robotiq gripper that you can easily attach to another robot: https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots_ros2/tree/master/webots_ros2_universal_robot (but you probably need some smaller gripper for the drone)
- Here is a DJI Mavic simulation: https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots_ros2/tree/master/webots_ros2_mavic

---

Originally posted by [lukicdarkoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/44970/lukicdarkoo/) with karma: 486 on 2022-01-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4